# Is putting "is_deleted" state field as composite primary key on cassandra table for read is good practice?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, reactive, spring-data-cassandra

I'm setting up new reactive cassandra rest service on spring, and then there is "default" field like `is_deleted`, `is_active`, `storeid`, etc, on all tables.

Since it's assumed that is_deleted needed on where query. 
It's created as one of the composite PK, so that the data search would be faster.

Problem is because of that, the primary key is very fat and the search query becomes so long since it need to mention all default key.

Is it a good practice to have such fat composite PK on cassandra?

```
@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = BaseCassandraFields.STORE_ID, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
  protected String storeId;

@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = BaseCassandraFields.IS_DELETED, type = 
PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
  protected Boolean isDeleted = false;
```

[Example of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlHUm.png)

[Also here is the DDL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dYdp.png)

Comment: can you post the table schema?

Comment: @PedroGordo i've put a link to the screenshot of table pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't affect Cassandra internally, but if you don't need all those keys, you're putting stress on the development part needlessly. I personally find it weird to have booleans in the PK, but your use case might justify it.
You could argue that maybe Cassandra has a bit of extra overhead calculating the hash for the key due to more columns, but I doubt that's significant since hash functions usually have high performance.